# Numpy: operations on columns (or rows) of NxM array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This may be a silly question, but I've just started using *numpy* and I have to figure out how to perform some simple operations.

Suppose that I have the 2x3 array

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
   [2, 4, 6]])
```

And that I want to perform some operation on the first column, for example subtract 1 to all the elements to get

```
array([[0, 3, 5],
   [1, 4, 6]])
```

How can I perform such an operation?

Comment: Look into slicing : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arr
# array([[1, 3, 5],
#        [2, 4, 6]])

arr[:,0] = arr[:,0] - 1     # choose the first column here, subtract one and 
                            # assign it back to the same column

arr
# array([[0, 3, 5],
#        [1, 4, 6]])
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I have searched high and low and only found the correct syntax here. I simply needed to know how to do `np.mean(dat[:,5])`  after using `genfromtxt` to read a csv file into a numpy array.  You wouldn't think that was so far off the beaten path.  But you nailed it for me.  Thank you very much

Comment: And actually, I am going to go back to `csv.read()` so I can preserve my index values which are a date and a time and show up  as `nan` in `genfromtxt`, now that I know how this works.  This is a great solution.  Thank goodness for Google leading me here.  And thank you for this answer being here to find.  I have to laugh, seeing all the related Q's that Google could have found first.  It works in mysterious ways.